# Topology Qual Question 1

Tags: general-topology

I was working on some old topology qualifying exam problems and got stuck on this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Consider the smallest equivalence relation  on $X = S^1 \times S^1$ such that $(x, y) \sim (y, x)$
for all $x, y \in S^1$. Compute the homology of the space $X / \sim$  (with the quotient topology).

Comment: Hi James, I just noticed you have not accepted any answers to any of your questions. You might want to consider doing that, assuming the answers satisfy you. Otherwise, you should ask for clarification. (I am somewhat attached to my reputation points, but it is also the polite thing to do.)

Comment: Oh! I never realized there was a way to accept answers or a point system. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can model $X$ as a quotient space of a triangle, where two consecutive sides are glued together consistently. The third side does not get identified with anything. You can see this by thinking of a torus as a square with opposite sides identified and then seeing what happens when you equate $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$. But you can deformation-retract the resulting space by pushing in from the unidentified edge of the triangle onto the two other edges. Then you get two line segments which are identified in such a way as to yield a circle. So the homology is the same as the homology of a circle.